# How do I change the order in automake's CXXLINK?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, autoconf, automake

I am trying to compile a simple C++ program with the automake tools. By itself, automake creates in its Makefile the line: `CXXLINK = $(CXXLD) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AM_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) \ -o $@`

This way, however, i get some linker errors, which can be resolved by simply putting the `-o example example.cpp` part in the beginning of the g++ command instead of the end.

How can I instruct automake to put the `-o example example.cpp` in front of the linker commands?

Here is the `Makefile.am`

```
bin_PROGRAMS = GLTest

GLTest_SOURCES = main.cpp

AM_CXXFLAGS=@gllibs_CFLAGS@ -std=c++11 -pthread
AM_LDFLAGS=@gllibs_LIBS@ -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr
```

Here are the linker errors:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/libdrm -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O2 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr  -o GLTest main.o  
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are resolved when I compile it manually like this:

```
g++ -o GLTest main.cpp -I/usr/include/libdrm -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O2 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr
```

Comment: What does your `Makefile.am` look like?

Comment: This is my Makefile.am:
`bin_PROGRAMS = GLTest`  
`GLTest_SOURCES = main.cpp`  
`AM_CXXFLAGS=@gllibs_CFLAGS@ -std=c++11 -pthread`  
`AM_LDFLAGS=@gllibs_LIBS@ -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr`

Comment: How is `@gllibs_LIBS@` being set? Did you try `$(gllibs_LIBS)` instead? Have you looked at `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` to locate the GL/X11 etc. libraries?

Comment: As I understand it, `gllibs_LIBS` is set by autoconfig. In my `configure.ac`, I have `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([gllibs], [gl glew glfw3 >= 3.0])` , doesn't that set those variables for me? `$(gllibs_LIBS)` doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: Can you post the actual link errors you get?

Comment: For the exact errors see OP. I shortened the file paths in the output.

Comment: Do you have `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL` in your `configure.ac`?

Comment: Installing `libtool` and adding `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL` in `configure.ac` solved it! Can you please add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linker command in the output it looks like you are not using `libtool`.

Try adding `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL` to the `configure.ac`.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. The problem is you're passing libraries as `LDFLAGS`, and that is incorrect.

You should have

```
GLTest_LDADD = $(gllibs_LIBS)
```

so that you're telling automake correctly that those are libraries.

Using libtool *may* work, depending on the libtool version used, since it can sort the command line, but it's still the wrong thing to do and fails in other situations.